# Replace values of a variable with the most frequent value, or the highest value in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I can't seem to find an example of this problem:

I would like to replace the values of a categorical variable (V1) with the most frequently occuring value per ID for new variable (V2). If there is no most frequent value in V1, I would like to replace with the highest value.

Here is an example of my data:

```
my_data <- data.frame(ID = c("2", "2", "2", "2" ,"4", "4", "4", "4"),
                      V1 = c("2", "1", "2", "1", "3", "1", "4", "3"))
```

[image: my_data]

This is what I would like it to look like:

[image: my_data_2]

Any help hugely appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to sort or `arrange` by the frequencies of each value `n` and the `V1` value secondarily. Then, for each `ID`, take the highest value of `n` first, followed by `V1`, and join back to original data (I modified data with two extra rows for example where there is no highest value for a given `ID`).

```
library(dplyr) # v1.1.0

my_data %>%
  count(ID, V1) %>%
  arrange(ID, desc(n), desc(V1)) %>%
  slice(1, .by = ID) %>%
  rename(V2 = V1) %>%
  right_join(my_data, multiple = "all") %>%
  select(ID, V1, V2)
```

**Output**

```
   ID V1 V2
1   2  2  2
2   2  1  2
3   2  2  2
4   2  1  2
5   4  3  3
6   4  1  3
7   4  4  3
8   4  3  3
9   5  6  7
10  5  7  7
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update(added max() and removed [1]):**

We could do it this way: Using `add_count`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  add_count(V1) %>% 
  mutate(V2 = max(V1[n==max(n)])) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-n)
```

```
  ID    V1    V2   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 2     2     2    
2 2     1     2    
3 2     2     2    
4 2     1     2    
5 4     3     3    
6 4     1     3    
7 4     4     3    
8 4     3     3
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to choose the highest value if all of the values occur the same number of times?

Comment: @TarJae This now gives same answer. +1